# Getting ip address of local computer connected to proxy server

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I am currently implementing a HTTP proxy server and i need to get the local computers' ip addresses connected to it. Note that I am not referring to the remote server's ip address and it's not an ASP.NET app but rather a desktop app. The user on a different computer will input the ip address and port number of the proxy server through a browser, say Mozilla Firefox for instance, and i really need to get the user's ip address.

I am looking everywhere over the internet and i can't find a decent solution. Any idea please?

Comment: If you are building a the proxy server can you not code it to get the clients IP address from the HTTP headers of the request?

Comment: `Socket` has a `RemoteEndPoint` property

Comment: The RemoteEndPoint property will give me the end point of the remote server which the user is making request to, not the user's ip address.

Comment: `I am currently implementing a HTTP proxy server`, when you write a server side code, *connected clients'* `RemoteEndPoint` will give you what you want. (Not the connection you make to the real remote server)

Comment: Can you post a piece of code please?

Comment: Can *you* show your code please?

Comment: Nevermind, i actually used the RemoteEndPoint property and it works. In fact, i was using it on the socket connecting to the remote server before, thats why i was getting what i wanted. Thanks anyway. :)